# Accessing Data from Python GAE Datastore using Java

Tags: java, android, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have set up a Google App Engine website project using Python, with the `webapp2` framework. It's neat and seems to be working perfectly. I can run queries in the backend of my website using python.

However, recently I've decided I want to have an Android (and maybe iOS) app as well as a website. The app will almost clone the website. Now, I have no idea how to query this data or access the datastore using Java, since up till now it's all been using the `ndb` import in Python.

How exactly would I approach this? I doubt that I need to create a new project in Java on GAE?

Has it something to do with Remote API? Looking into that now. And if so, it seems like none is available for Swift language.

Should I consider using a different Database system, and forget about GAE?

I only wish to read the data in Java, not write to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can use Cloud [Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/). You expose the information you want on an API, and you consume it from iOS or Android. [Here](http://rominirani.com/2014/08/25/gradle-tutorial-part-8-gradle-app-engine-endpoints-android-studio/) there is a tutorial that covers it.